# How to Assign values to varying range of cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, random, vlookup

I am trying randomly generate a whole number between 1 and 100, whether that be in a cell or in the vba code directly. Then I want to use that value as the lookup value for a `VLookup` that will pull another randomly generated whole number between 1 and 10 from a different sheet. Then I want to use that second number between 1 and 10 as an indicator to fill in that many cells in a column with the first number between 1 and 100.

So for example if I were doing it manually: I would have in cell "C27" on Sheet1 `=MROUND(RANDBETWEEN(1,100),1)`. Let's say it returns 40. Then I would look on Sheet2 for number 40 in column A, look over to Column D where there is another `=MROUND(RANDBETWEEN(1,10),1)`. Let's say that one returns 5 (so I need to fill in 5 cells of a column). Then I would head back to Sheet1 and enter 40 into cells K31 through K35 (the original random whole number).

I'm aware that `RAND` and `RANDBETWEEN` update anytime the worksheet recalculates. I use triggered IF statements to keep them from updating unless I change a value in a trigger cell. If generating a random number with VBA makes that even easier, I'm all for it.

I don't think it will be helpful for me to post the many iterations I've attempted as I've tried to apply solutions to each individual task of this macro. None of them have seemingly even gotten me close. But here's what I'm using right now that's also not even close. This code was for me to try and get it to work period. So the numbers are static and not random. But I need them random.  And yes, this is for me to generate random monsters for my D&D game mastering :)

Thanks to anyone who might be able to get me on the right track!

```
Sub MonsterRoll()
'
' MonsterRoll

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim roll As Integer
Dim No1 As Integer
Dim No2 As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("Combat Helper")
roll = 5
No1 = 31
No2 = 31 + 5

On Error Resume Next
For i = No1 To No2
    area.Cells(i, 11).Value = 5
Next

End Sub
```

[This table houses the vlookups into sheet "Encounters"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvEHN.png)

[This table contains the source data, with column D being a RANDBETWEEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzvTl.png)

Comment: More info is needed: (1) Can any of your random numbers be repeated? i.e. can you have '40' generated twice? (2) How is column 'K' determined? is it an offset, or random? (since your example returned a '5'...) (3) Is Sheet2 built on the fly, and can change between visits?

Comment: Comment too long so splitting into two:

1) Yes, 40 can be returned twice, although I would be interested to know how to generate random numbers without replacement.

2) I'm not exactly sure what you mean (i'm not familiar with offsets yet) but I'll try to elaborate. Sheet1 cells K31:K50 are empty. If a value from 1-100 is entered into any cell from K31:K50, then A:G of that row are set to vlookup the value of K and populate with corresponding values from Sheet2. So If I enter 40 into K31, then A31:J31 will populate with values from Sheet2.

Comment: How many cells between K31:K50 are filled with "40" is variable and determined by one of the values on Sheet2, specifically column D. Column D on Sheet2 includes the "number of monsters appearing" for each monster 1 through 100. the "number of monsters appearing" is random between 1-10 (though it could be 1-4, 1-8, etc based on which monster number it is. Using 1-10 here for ease).

Comment: In the real world, I would roll dice and return 40. I'd look up monster #40 which would tell me what dice to roll to determine how many monster #40's appear.  Based on how many monster #40s appear, I want to fill in that many cells from K31:K50 with the number 40. Then the vlookups in A:J will pull the necessary facts about monster #40.

Comment: The range K31-K50 is static. The number of cells from K31-K50 that I want filled in must be dynamic and responsive to the randomly generated number from Column D on Sheet2. The row from which the random number in Column D on Sheet2 is determine by the initial random number from 1-100. 

Sheet2 is static, although I may replace monsters from time to time. But yes, sheet 2 is filled with static values EXCEPT column D which is the =MROUND(RANDBETWEEN(1,10),1)... or 1,4 or 1,8... etc.

Comment: Still confused. (1) You say "then A:G of that row are set to vlookup the value of K ...So If I enter 40 into K31, then A31:J31 will populate..."Which is it? A-G or A-J?  (2) You use a VLOOKUP based on value in col. K (R31-50) Which col on Sheet2 will contain match of 1-100? (3) You say "Vlookups in A:J", but what ranges? What content? (4) How about a simple sample of three rows where you show what is in each cell for Sheet1 and Sheet2 - is it a value or a lookup?

Comment: I added images. Apologies for the A:G mix-up, was typing quickly before running out the door. 

Column A in SHeet2 contains the match for the vlookups. 

THe vlookups in A:J are A31:J50.

Content is both text and numeric.

In the pictures, "Combat Helper" is sheet1, "Encounters" is sheet2 as I've been referring to them here.

Comment: Crimeny I keep saying A;J but the vlookups are A31:H51. columns I & J are used as triggers for other RANDBETWEEN equations elsewhere, and controlled by a short and simple vba I was able to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure about a few cell references, but think I have a general idea.  The code below can be a starting point to do most of what you want -- with a few warnings...

Since you are monitoring for changes in Sheet1 cells K31:K50, and then making changes to that same range, that will trigger the change event again.  So, to avoid crazy results, I added a flag so that it will ignore changes untill you tell it to stop ignoring. That will be when you have finished all processing for your original change.

Personally, I would prefer to generate my own random numbers via code for the simple reason that ANY change to any cell will trigger all of your 'random' numbers to regenerate.

Go to Function 'Set_All_Cell_Values' and add whatever code you need to fill other cells.

```
Option Explicit

Dim blnIgnoreChanges    As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws1     As Worksheet
Dim ws2     As Worksheet
Dim i       As Integer
Dim iYourNbr    As Integer
Dim iMyNbr  As Integer
Dim iRow    As Integer
Dim iHowMany    As Integer
Dim Why     As String

    ' The following code can be dangerous if your code is not working properly!!!!
    ' Since you want to 'monitor' changes to K31:K50, and then change those same cells via code,
    ' which will in turn trigger this 'Worksheet_Change' subroutine to fire again,
    ' you need to be able to ignore changes on demand.
    ' If this flag gets set and your code didn't complete (AND turn the flag off), then
    ' any monitoring of future changes will be ignored!!
    ' If the flag fails to get reset, then just execute the following code in the immediate window:
    '  blnIgnoreChanges =  false

    If blnIgnoreChanges = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combat Helper")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Encounters")

' Sample data in Sheet2
' A       B          C   D   E    F  G   H    I   J
'40  Bird, Falcon    1   1   1   -10 5   2   1d4  t
'41  Men: Wild Man   2   3   2   -9  2   3   1d5  u
'42  Beast           3   5   3   -8  3   4   1d6  v
'43  Elephant        4   7   4   -7  4   5   1d7  w

    ' Monitor only cells K31:K50
    If Target.Row >= 31 And Target.Row <= 50 And Target.Column = 11 Then
        ' Value must be between 1 and 100
        If Target.Value < 1 Or Target.Value > 100 Then
            MsgBox "Must enter between 1 and 100"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ' If you want to Lookup match in Col A of Sheet2, and then get value from col D.
            iYourNbr = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, ws2.Range("A3:N102"), 4, False)
            ' I prefer to Generate my own random number between 1 and 10
            iMyNbr = Int((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
            iRow = Find_Matching_Value(Target.Value)
            Debug.Print "Matching Row in Sheet2 is: " & iRow

            ' DANGER!! If you execute the following line of code, then you MUST set to FALSE
            ' when you have finished one change!!!
            blnIgnoreChanges = True

            iHowMany = Sheet2.Cells(iRow, 4).Value
            Sheet1.Cells(Target.Row, 13) = iHowMany
            Set_All_Cell_Values Target.Row, iRow, iHowMany


        End If
    ' We can ignore all other cell changes
    Else
        'Debug.Print "Change made to: " & "R" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Column & " but not my row or column!   Value is:" & Target.Value
    End If

End Sub

Function Set_All_Cell_Values(iS1Row As Integer, iS2Row As Integer, iHowMany As Integer)
Dim i       As Integer

    Debug.Print "Add code to set cells for Sheet1 R:" & iS1Row & " Sheet2 R:" & iS2Row

    For i = iS1Row + 1 To iS1Row + iHowMany - 1
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 11) = Sheet1.Cells(iS1Row, 11)

        '#################################################
        ' ADD CODE TO FILL OTHER CELLS as needed!!!
        '#################################################
    Next i

    blnIgnoreChanges = False
End Function

Function Find_Matching_Value(iFind As Integer) As Integer
Dim Rng     As Range
    If Trim(iFind) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Encounters").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=iFind, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Find_Matching_Value = Rng.Row
            Else
                MsgBox "Did not find match for value: " & iFind
            End If
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "You passed an empty value to 'Find_Matching_Value'"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for taking on my case, Wayne. It's going to take me a little while to unpack, digest, and apply this. Hopefully you might answer any follow-up questions I have. Regardless, upvoting as solution since it looks like this is going to get me rolling!